# turn vertical list to horizontal list start new row when change in column A, B and E

Tags: vba, formula

I have a list of data that I need to turn from vertical to horizontal... I would like to do it via VBA as I have about 40K lines. I need to have it combine all data for each number group with the same type, prod and G/NG code. So all that have the same type, Prod, G/NG and Number need to be in one column with all from the Code column in the row....

For example

Starting with

```
Number|Type  | Code |Prod  |G/NG  |
:----:|:----:|:----:|:----:|:----:|
440     AF     1234   S7      G
440     AF     7865   S7      G
440     NY     1235   S7      G
440     NY     4567   S7      G
41MM    AF     1234   S7      G
41MM    AF     1235   S7      NG
```

Should now look like:

```
Number|Type  | Code1 | Code2| Prod  |G/NG  |
:----:|:----:|:----: |:----:|:-----:|:----:|
440     AF     1234    7865    S7      G
```

Comment: So would 41mm still be two rows since G/NG do not match?

Comment: it can be done with array formula, no need for VBA, are the in columns or single cells?

Comment: I haven't be able to get anything to work that i've tried. I tried doing a match formula but that didn't work and I can't think of a VBA way to do it so that's why i'm here I have done VBA for at a break of in one column but not one that is for 3 columns.

Comment: Yes Scott Craner it would have two rows

Comment: I tried an array formula but it didn't work either.....

Comment: What would be the max number of "codex" columns in any given row in the resulting table?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite common on this site that the detail in responses matches the effort you show in your question ... and let's face it, yours shows almost none. It's also true that you need to present some code that you've tried but can't get to work as you'd hoped. I note from your previous questions that you've simply posted code you've found on the net and asked people to adjust it for you. So most respondents on this site will be wondering this: do you merely want to lift other people's code and get SO to amend it or do you actually want to learn VBA?

I'm going to assume it's the latter (in the hope that your future questions demonstrate some 'first principles' coding) and help you along with the solution to this question. Although it's a fairly trivial project, there are some fiddly aspects to it and I can see how you wouldn't know where to start.

You basically have 2 tasks:

1. Find how many unique rows you have according to your criteria,
2. Find the maximum number of codes.

The first task is simply a case of looping through each row and seeing if each details combination is a new one. There are many ways of doing this - the code below uses a `Collection` with the details combination as a key.

For the second task you would add all the codes to their respective product, keeping a note of the largest count of codes. You'll see in the sample code, I've used a second `Collection`.

There are many other ways of handling this (eg with jagged arrays) and if, for example, the details for each product aren't unique, you'll have to get a bit more creative.

Once you have the data appropriately divided you would then populate each row of an output array with your items and write the array to your sheet. In the code below, I've written it to `Sheet2`so that you don't lose your original data.

So, here's the code which I hope will get you started. Please try to work through it yourself and ensure you understand it ... which means avoid adding comments to this post along the lines of "Oh, such and such a line doesn't work."

```
Dim data As Variant
Dim products As Collection, details As Collection, codes As Collection
Dim detailsKey As String
Dim code As Variant, output() As Variant
Dim maxCodeSize As Long
Dim r As Long, c As Long

'Read data into array
With Sheet1 '~~> adjust this to your data sheet
    data = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)).Value2
End With

'Loop through rows to create unqiue product entries
Set products = New Collection
For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)

    'Create the keys
    detailsKey = CStr(data(r, 1)) & "|" & _
                 CStr(data(r, 2)) & "|" & _
                 CStr(data(r, 4)) & "|" & _
                 CStr(data(r, 5))

    'Test if product exists
    Set details = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set details = products(detailsKey)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If it doesn't exist add a new product to collection
    If details Is Nothing Then
        Set details = New Collection
        With details
            .Add data(r, 1), "NUMBER"
            .Add data(r, 2), "TYPE"
            .Add data(r, 4), "PROD"
            .Add data(r, 5), "G/NG"
            .Add New Collection, "CODES"
        End With
        products.Add details, detailsKey
    End If

    'Add the codes, keeping a note of max code count
    Set codes = details("CODES")
    codes.Add data(r, 3)
    If maxCodeSize < codes.Count Then
        maxCodeSize = codes.Count
    End If

Next

'Size the output array
ReDim output(1 To details.Count + 1, 1 To 4 + maxCodeSize)

'Fill header row
output(1, 1) = "Number"
output(1, 2) = "Type"
For c = 1 To maxCodeSize
    output(1, 2 + c) = "Code" & c
Next
output(1, 3 + maxCodeSize) = "Prod"
output(1, 4 + maxCodeSize) = "G/NG"

'Fill data rows
r = 2
For Each details In products
    output(r, 1) = details("NUMBER")
    output(r, 2) = details("TYPE")
    c = 1
    Set codes = details("CODES")
    For Each code In codes
        output(r, 2 + c) = code
        c = c + 1
    Next
    output(r, 3 + maxCodeSize) = details("PROD")
    output(r, 4 + maxCodeSize) = details("G/NG")
    r = r + 1
Next

'Write output to Sheet2
Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
```